# Value passing through channels

Tags: uppaal

According to 
http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/darts/uppaal/small_tutorial.pdf
There is no value passing through the channels but this is easily encoded by shared variable: define globally a variable x, and use it for reading and writing. "

The Train-Gate example that accompanies Uppaal seems to perform the communication of a value via a channel. I have also created a small example where a producer counts in a loop from 1 to 6 and communicates `comm[getN()]!` on a channel comm (`getN()` simply retrieves the local variable). A consumer syncs with this communication `comm[n]?` and stores the passed integer value in a local variable.

This seems to contradict the above statement. Am I missing something subtle here? Is this not passing values through channels? Or it this statement simply not true any longer?

I have included my full example (producer-consumer.xml) via Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/ZTL46Wr8

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your model there is no value passing. Actually you mimic the value passing using synchronization of channels with the same name: comm[n]! where n is actually a variable and comm[k]? where k is a selector i.e. a constant value. The consumer does not actually receive the value of n; it receives the information that comm[n] has been emitted for some fixed value of n.

Comment: Thanks - that helps me understand what goes on.

Two small follow-up questions:
1) Is it better to mimic values passing via channels like above, or via global state (as the comment indicates)? the global state seems awkward as for multiple communications you need multiple global variables and need to be very careful and verbose.

2) Are they scaling problems when it comes to verifications/simulation?

Comment: @Liam value passing via channel arrays uses edge enumeration, thus requires more effort to enumerate them and match the channels than simple shared variable assignment.